# how assign roles in the Moodle

Tags: moodle

I installed moodle and want to assign roles. in Site administration/Users/Permissions/Define roles I have 8 roles. But in administration/Users/Permissions/Assign system roles I have only 2 roles to assign. How can I assign a user the role not exists in these two?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you define a role, you can specify which contexts the roles can be assigned in - it is a list of checkboxes near the top of the form you get when you click on 'Edit' for a role.

Most roles (teacher, student, etc.) are designed to be assigned at the 'course' level, so go to a course, click on 'Users > Show enroled users' and then enrol users there with specific roles.

Comment: thanks but when I want to assign roles still it has 2 roles, I can't add roles. As you said I just can step by step do the various roles to various people. But just have 2 roles, Manager and course creator

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the context. If its a system context, then they will be available in the system roles section

If its a user context then you need to go to the individual user

site admin -> users -> browse list of users -> click on a users name

this will give you the users profile

Then go to

profile settings for "users name" -> roles > assign roles relative to this user

It's a bit of a long way round but that's how it works.

http://docs.moodle.org/26/en/Parent_role

Comment: Thanks a lot. I did that but I can't assign roles. There is a text box and is written "There is no role for this user in this site". And another problem is I can't add a role by myself. It's a select box I should choose only

Comment: I can't find that string "There is no role for this user in this site" in Moodle 2.5 or 2.6 - is that a translation?

Comment: yes in fact it's a translation. because I installed with another language. I went to moodle demo but it has role so I couldn't find the exact sentence.

Comment: in the demo it has those 2 roles only  too. maybe that's better to ask like this:"I have a user and want to be a teacher. what should I do?"

Comment: Ah, in which case Davosmith has the answer, you assign teachers at the course level. If its only showing 2 roles at that stage, then the roles aren't defined. Check that you have a teacher role defined, go to /admin/roles/manage.php